# Blue screen of death and memory dump hangs for hours

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod, dump

I got a BSoD and it completed dumping physical memory, but it hangs for hours, and there's nothing moving.

What should I do?

My computer is running Win7 x64.

The dump reached 100 but then nothing occurs.

Comment: how large is the pagefile?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the "Automatically restart" check box checked in Start -> Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings (far left) -> Advanced tab (at the top) -> Startup and Recovery settings button, it's going to hang at the BSoD until you physically reset it.

If this is checked, you have an ACPI driver issue, a BIOS issue, or a physical issue with your motherboard.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would ask you this as a comment but don't have the reps for it so here it goes.

**What level of dump do you have?**

[ Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Startup & Recovery ]

Obviously it is not `(none)`, so its either `(small memory dump 256k)` which is unlikely given how long you say its taking or `(kernel memory dump)` which is most likely what you have set. The last one CAN take a long time but shouldn't be taking hours either unless you have A LOT of memory or huge allocation of virtual memory in your swap file.

To check the latter (virtual memory and swap file size)

[ Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Performance -> Advanced -> Change ]

If this is managed by the system and your drive is not unusually large, you should be fine. If you are manually doing it and have a large size, either reduce it or auto manage it. Or if performance is not an issue for you, just set to no paging.

**NOTE:** Compared to the other answer which came while I was preparing this, I am assuming you have the restart checked and based on what you said, you are seeing the blue screen show a progress of the dump or at least trying even if the progress is frozen. If you don't have auto restart checked, then do it and it will not hang.

Comment: Memory dump progress is at 100 and it took only seconds

Comment: I am not sure how my setting is, but last time I had bsod, computer restarted automatically.

Comment: In that case if its finishing the dump and sitting there still, you do not have the auto restart checked. Just go to the same place I gave you directions for setting the dump level and its a checkbox above it, just like the one @ultrasawblade posted in the screenshot.

Comment: what is the defaul setting for that..?

Comment: Well I hate to say it, but it depends. However, GENERALLY, it is set to automatically restart but some things can change that.